# C# Constructor Design when passed variable might be one of two types

Tags: c#, class, constructor

The constructor for my class has three variables passed to it:

```
public MyClass(int Id, String Name, DateTime StartDate)
```

But, `StartDate` might be passed into the variable as a `String` or as a `DateTime` object.

Should I create two different constructors one specifying `DateTime` for `StartDate` and one as `String`? Or, should I make the type `Dynamic` and determine what it is at run time and handle it then? I ask because my class has five dates and if I were to write constructors for every different combination, that would be way too much code.

Comment: Why not do a `Convert.ToDateTime` to the string *before* you put it into the constructor, so that you always get a `DateTime`?

Comment: Why is it you need to support every combination of this?  Is there really a place in your code where you need to pass in 3 `DateTime`s and 2 `String`s?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define an overload of the constructor that calls your default constructor:

```
class MyClass
{
    public MyClass(int id, string name, DateTime startDate)
    {
    }

    public MyClass(int id, string name, string startDate)
        : this(id, name, DateTime.Parse(startDate))
    {
    }
}
```

I would only create a constructor that accepts all as DateTime objects and an overload that accepts all as strings. I would ignore any other combination. In fact, I would only accept DateTime.

Accepting a dynamic type would result in a poor interface.

Answer (score 6):

You should make the callers more strongly typed instead of ["stringly" typed](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2012/07/new-programming-jargon.html).

Create one constructor that takes 5 dates, and force the callers to do the right thing. That seems a lot more sane than 25 constructors that all have to do the right thing.

Answer (score 1):

String conversion to DateTime objects can be risky.  Not all strings can be accurately converted.  For example, consider these dates:

- 02-03-2012 - Is this date UK-style, which would be March 2nd, or US-style date, which would be February 3rd?
- Jan 3 - Which year?
- 1/30/15 - Does this refer to Janary 30th in 1915 or 2015?

Before you can be certain whether strings can be legitimately converted to DateTimes reliably throughout your application, you need to know what types of conversion risk you have.  `DateTime.TryParse` is a fantastic function, but it can't solve all potential problems.

I would recommend that, in your constructor, you insist on strongly typed data - e.g. DateTime objects:

```
public MyClass(int id, string name, DateTime StartDate)
```

Then, move the parsing of the strings close to where those strings are obtained.  For example, if your strings are loaded from a source data file, you can parse those strings in the file's loading code and throw exceptions on errors.  As another example, if the strings are typed by a user, you can throw exceptions when the user mistypes the date directly.